# Centering an array of DIVs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a bunch of divs with a fixed size. I want it to work with a relative/unspecified window size. The code below works so long as the divs don't wrap around to the next line. As soon as they wrap, everything gets aligned to the left. The plan is to dynamically generate lots of these and have it be vertically scrollable only. My CSS skills are pretty weak. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto; 
  display: table;
}
.block {
  background: #999; 
  float: left; 
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px; 
  margin: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="block">1</div>
 <div class="block">2</div>
 <div class="block">3</div>
 <div class="block">4</div>
     <!--
 <div class="block">5</div>
 <div class="block">6</div>
 <div class="block">7</div>
 <div class="block">8</div>
 <div class="block">9</div>
 <div class="block">10</div>
 <div class="block">11</div>
 <div class="block">12</div>
 <div class="block">13</div>
 <div class="block">14</div>
 <div class="block">15</div>
    -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left` and then give `text-align:center;` to their parent and don't forget to [remove extra spaces](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) which is occurred by `display:inline-block;`

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto; 
  display: table;
  text-align:center;
}
.block {
  background: #999; 
  /* float: left; */
  display:inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px; 
  margin: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="block">1</div>
 <div class="block">2</div>
 <div class="block">3</div>
 <div class="block">4</div>
 <div class="block">5</div>
 <div class="block">6</div>
 <div class="block">7</div>
 <div class="block">8</div>
 <div class="block">9</div>
 <div class="block">10</div>
 <div class="block">11</div>
 <div class="block">12</div>
 <div class="block">13</div>
 <div class="block">14</div>
 <div class="block">15</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```